# Condition Issue NetSuite Email Merge from SuiteScript With Template Using Freemarker

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, freemarker

I'm working on some functionality that sends out notification emails. There may or may not be a contact specified. So when I initially set up the mail merge, this is what I'm doing:

```
var template = nlapiCreateEmailMerger(_TEMPLATE_ID);
template.setEntity("customer", customerId);
if (!isEmpty(contactID)) {
    template.setEntity("contact", contactID);
}
```

Because there may or may not be a contact specified, in my email template I have Freemarker in place to check to see if a contact is there. If so, it adds their first and last name. If not, it adds the "companyname" value from the customer record. This is what I have:

```
<#if contact.id?has_content>${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}<#else>${customer.companyName}</#if>
```

The issue that I'm having is that when a contact is added, it displays the contact name just fine. However, if no contact is added, the conditional statement fails completely. Nothing shows up at all, even if "companyname" has a value. I've tried the following, but the conditional statement always resolves to **false**:

```
<#if contact?has_content>${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}<#else>${customer.companyName}</#if>
```

I've tried seeing what's going on, and if I place all of the values outside of the conditional statement, I get values when I expect them, and blank space when I expect it. So I know there is no issue with the data itself, as far as I can tell.

I know I can get around this by creating two separate templates and picking the correct one in the script, but that becomes trouble when having to make changes and I'd prefer to only have one template to maintain.

So, I suppose the real question is, what is the appropriate value to use in the condition statement that works whether or not a contact record is added?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had an epiphany and solved the issue. In hindsight, it was pretty obvious. Here's what I did.

I basically created a variable, and set it to be the "companyname" value. Then, if there was a contact, assign it the contact's name. Here's the code:

```
<#assign greeting = customer.companyName>
<#if contact.id?has_content><#assign greeting = contact.firstName + " " + contact.lastName></#if>
${greeting},<br />
```

I hope this helps someone else.